# How to keep other images immovable when one of them is becoming larger?

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<img id="btnLeft" src="img/btnLeft.png"/>
<img id="logo01" src="img/logo01.png"/>
```

CSS

```
#btnLeft{heigth:64px;}
#btnLeft:hover{height:74px;}
```

On mouseover `btnLeft` pushes `#logo01` down by 10px.
I want `#logo01` to stay in place.

Comment: What happens when you mouse over btnLeft? Does btnLeft get larger?

Comment: @levib, yes it becomes larger.

Comment: Let me guess, by 10px in height?

Comment: We don't have the appropriate code to work with, though a naughty hack could be `#btnLeft:hover + #logo01 { margin-top: -10px; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate div for your image elements, float them left or right depending on your preference and then use use `vertical-align: top` on the containing `div`. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/94zVg/.

The reason for this issue is because you have to image elements side by side which will be aligned to the bottom of their containing block. When one image is enlargened, it expands the containing block and the other element descends to stick to the bottom of it. Floating and aligning vertically solve this problem.

Comment: @Asad, Thanks for your attention, levib's post gave me an idea with a div as a container for `#btnLeft.` It works.

Answer (score 1):

Give the first image a width as well, otherwise its width will expand proportionally and push the adjacent image down.

```
#btnLeft{height:64px;width:100px;}
#btnLeft:hover{height:74px;}
```

Here is a demonstration with explicit width: http://jsfiddle.net/XRKK4/

Here is a demonstration without explicit width: http://jsfiddle.net/XRKK4/1/